# Justify text in labelitemi

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I have used the below command to change the size of the bullet

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{{\tiny$\bullet$}}
```

The text inside the bullet is not justified. How can I justify the text within the bullets.

Also, I have many bullet points, so I want to declare it globally, so that I do not have to repeat it again and again for each bullet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `enumitem` and it's `label=...` feature within `\setlist`, which does not require to set the label each time. It's set for all `itemize` environments then. If this is not requested, a new list can cloned.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize,1]{label={\tiny\textbullet}}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\foreach \x in {1,...,15} {
\item \x
}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How is it different from labelitemi?

Comment: @blackmamba: You don't have to this each time...

Comment: Thanks Christian. Foreach command is printing the statement in \item 15 times, which is expected as it is a for loop. How can I set this up for all bullet points? It is not justifying the line.

Comment: The `\foreach` is just for demo -- the setup is already done in the `label=...` statement of `\setlist`

Comment: I tried removing the foreach command, the text is not justified plus the bullet points are really small compared to what I had in labelitemi

Comment: @blackmamba: What do you expect using `\tiny`? And there is no need to use `\bullet`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31380/discussion-between-blackmamba-and-christian-hupfer).

Comment: I am saying when I had labelitemi, the size of bullet was different. I am not using \bullet now. I am using \item. My point is, the text is not getting justified.

Comment: This worked. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Smaller bullets can indeed be a good stylistic choice. However, just `\tiny\textbullet` (that's essentially the same as `\tiny$\bullet$`) will print the small bullet too low.

One can raise it automatically by exploiting `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{%
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny\textbullet}}$%
}

\begin{document}

Compare $\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny\textbullet}}$ with \textbullet

This is an itemized list:
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
and this is another one
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
where you see that redeclaring \verb|\labelitemi| is
not necessary.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more flexible command that allows the bullet to change its size in different contexts (say for itemized lists in footnotes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\smallerbullet{0.3em}} % <-- fix the diameter here
\DeclareRobustCommand{\smallerbullet}[1]{%
  $\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{#1}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \put(0.5,0.5){\circle*{1}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item 0.1em \smallerbullet{0.1em} and \textbullet
\item 0.15em \smallerbullet{0.15em} and \textbullet
\item 0.2em \smallerbullet{0.2em} and \textbullet
\item 0.25em \smallerbullet{0.25em} and \textbullet
\item 0.3em \smallerbullet{0.3em} and \textbullet
\item 0.35em \smallerbullet{0.35em} and \textbullet
\end{itemize}

This is an itemized list:
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
and this is another one
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
where you see that redeclaring \verb|\labelitemi| is
not necessary.

\end{document}
```

Once you have decided for the diameter that suits your taste, set it in the redefinition of `\labelitemi`. The top itemized list has a comparison of the new bullet with the standard one to help in the choice.

[image]